# Return selected parameter from linq object

Tags: c#, linq

I have an entity:

```
public class Branch
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int BranchID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string Postcode { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

I have an apicontroller function to return the branches object:

```
IEnumerable<Branch> branches = null;
branches = repository.Branches.Where(b => b.LastModified > modifiedSince).AsEnumerable();

return branches;
```

How can I return only `BranchID` and `Name` ?

I have tried this:

```
IEnumerable<Branch> branches = null;

branches = repository.Branches
    .Where(b => b.LastModified > modifiedSince)
    .Select(b => new Branch  {BranchID = b.BranchID, Name = b.Name })
    .AsEnumerable();

return branches;
```

Comment: You tried and what wrong happened?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. All that depends on how you're going to process the returned `IEnumerable<Branch>`.

1) You could do with an anonymous type, but returning it would take more hacks.

```
var branches =  repository.Branches
                          .Where(b => b.LastModified > modifiedSince)
                          .Select(b => new { b.BranchID, b.Name })
                          .AsEnumerable();
```

2) Or you could return a tuple of `id` and `name`.

```
var branches =  repository.Branches
                          .Where(b => b.LastModified > modifiedSince)
                          .Select(b => Tuple.Create(b.BranchID, b.Name))
                          .AsEnumerable();
return branches;
```

3) You may want to create your own class which holds just the id and name of a branch.

4) Or may be you could provide an alternate constructor for branch class with just the `name` and `id` passed as arguments. All that depends on your context.

I tend to prefer the tuple approach here.